# How to speed up the database encryption / decryption process in Oracle 11 Standard Edition?

Tags: encryption

I have an 11-year old huge database designed in Oracle 11g Standard Edition. It requires to be encrypted for maximum security.
We have used dbms_crypto library to perform the encryption & decryption but it is consuming a lot of time decrypt & display.
Our customers need to wait in ques for hours till our public-facing systems & applications can decrypt the 'data-at-rest' & 'data-in-transit'.

We are not going for the Oracle updated & Enterprise edition. So, any help & inputs for our current situation are extremely welcome!

Comment: Sorry but this question is related to a product, you may ask on the corresponding forum or support site of the brand product

Comment: This is not a question *about* security. I would point you to another Stack Exchange site, but there is simply not a question in there.